# Wrong custom option translations when creating order manually in Magento Admin

Tags: magento2

I have the following problem.

When I create an order manually via Magento Admin, custom option titles are wrong - they are taken from the wrong store. However, when I add the product, the titles are correct but as soon as I submit the order, they are wrong. See screenshots attached below.

It's Magento 2.4.1. Multi-store.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Correct titles:**
[image: Correct titles]

**Wrong titles:**
[image: Wrong titles]